# Which type of 7 branch menorah can I buy from the online Judaica stores to keep in my house?

Tags: halacha, menorah--in-temple

Ever since I started learning about Judaism, I noticed that Israel’s emblem contains a 7 branch menorah, not the chanukiah (which everyone, including tons of Jews) call a menorah.

I understand that the 7 branch was in the Temple and depicted on the Arch of Titus. I’m considering buying a 7 branch menorah for my house.

I've found some wildly differing opinions online. Some say none are permitted, some say they're permitted provided that they are either non-metal (I see a bunch of enamel), some say all of the types I see online are permitted but simply cannot be lit. Which is the truth?

I also know Israel itself had a debate when the Knesset Menorah was given to it, but the chief rabbi at the time ultimately decided it was halachic.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). 
Hope to see you around!

Comment: What would be the purpose of having such a menorah in your house?

Comment: as a decoration and to have the eternal symbol of the Jewish people in my house.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud in Rosh haShana 24b mentions a dispute as to if a wooden 7 branched menorah would be permissible, with all agreeing that a metal one is forbidden and that one made from pottery is permissable.

I'm not quite sure which category enamel would fall into, as as far as I can tell it is a kind of glass coating, normally on pottery.